# What does it mean "the airport has the code A 129" (Nida airport, Europe)?

Tags: airport

It has been announced that [Nida airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nida_Airport) ([Lithuania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nida,_Lithuania)) officially opens again and obtains the code "A 129" ([here](http://lzinios.lt/lzinios/Gimtasis-krastas/neringos-politikai-nori-oro-uosto/224891)). The source does not say that kind of code it is and what does it mean. Would it be possible to clarify? Is it a place designation, or the airport category?

Nida airport has been closed for many years. It is not very tiny, passenger planes used to land there many years ago. Recently it has been reopened for very small planes while probably something bigger would be able to land there as well. Basically this rather long runway has the status of untowered airstrip.

Nida airport has ICAO code EYND and no IATA code.

Comment: I can't find any information on it (the Lithuanian CAA site doesn't have published regulations, at least not in English) but I'm guessing that its a class of aircraft operations that are allowed on the airport.

Comment: I tried to find such information myself. There is little to none recent information about the airport as it has been closed for many years. I just wanted to as if A 129 tells maybe something to somebody immediately.

Comment: @ymb1: Ok. There is a bit of information [here](http://aerodromes.eu/EYND).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just an educated guess, but it sounds like it was assigned that identifier by the Lithuanian civil aviation authority. It obviously didn't warrant an IATA code. Since it was closed to most traffic the ICAO code may not have been in use. The wiki page said it was just considered an "airstrip," so it was assigned an ID by the government. (It also mentioned lack of fuel service. That might be a requirement for an ICAO registration. I don't know.)

Here in the US large airports will have an IATA CODE, an ICAO code and an FAA location ID. [example: O'Hare airport - IATA: ORD - ICAO: KORD - FAA: ORD] A small GA airport won't merit an IATA or ICAO code but it will have an FAA location ID. The small airport near where I work has no IATA or ICAO code. It has the FAA location identifier K68.

Comment: USA has more small airports than most other places. In Europe even the smallest air strips generally do have ICAO codes.